# Asymptotic Directions of a Cylinder

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, curves

Say I am looking at a cylinder. I have found the shape operator and I have found the eigenvalues to be k1 = -1/a and k2=0. I have also found the principal directions 
{1,0} and {0,1}. I know that if k1k2 <= 0 then there should be asymptotic directions. How can I find the asymptotic directions? How can I identify the lines of curvature and asymptotic curves?

Note: The cylinder is parameterized by: X(u,v) = (acosu, asinu, v).

Comment: Don't vandalize your own post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that because the coordinate directions are principal directions, the coordinate curves are lines of curvature. If $k_2=0$, the $v$-curves are necessarily asymptotic curves (as well as lines of curvature).

Comment: Thank you! I figured it out last night I solved the differential equation . Thank you Ted!!